# If $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}$, and $d>\frac12$, does it follow that $\frac{a}{b}<2c$?

Tags: inequality

$a,b,c$ and $d$ are positive non-zero real numbers.

If

$$
\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}
$$

and $d>\frac12$, is the following always true:

$$
\frac{a}{b}<2c
$$

I think yes but this is the kind of scenario in which I always make mistakes.

I don't intuitively understand these kinds of inequality manipulations, I'd really appreciate an answer that explains why the above is true or why it isn't true, rather than just a yes/no.

Comment: Consider $\frac{c}{d}$. That is, we divide $c$ by $d$. If we divide $c$ by something which is greater than $d$, we make the fraction smaller, but $d>\frac{1}{2}$, thus dividing by $\frac{1}{2}$ will make it greater. Thus $\frac{c}{d}>\frac{c}{\frac{1}{2}}=2c$. That's how you can think a bit more intuitive about this.

Comment: @theonlygusti  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$
\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}\quad \text{and}\quad d>\frac{1}{2}
$$
from the second one 
$$
d>\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow 2d>1\Rightarrow 2>\frac{1}{d}\Rightarrow 2c>\frac{c}{d}
$$
(the sign doesn't turn since all of the numbers are positive).
And you can just write everything in one chain
$$
\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}< 2c.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Here is one way to reason about it:

If $\frac12<d$, then $\frac1d<2$. Multiply that by $c$, and we get $\frac cd< 2c$. Since $<$ is transitive, we can chain this together with $\frac ab <\frac cd$ to get $\frac ab < 2c$

Answer (score 0):

If $d >1/2$ then $1/d<2$ and then $c/d<2c$.